# Zip Lists Resulting in Instantiation of Object and Adding to Collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

I have a class `Song` with properties `Title` and `URL`.

I also have two `List<string>` collections, `titles` and `URLs`, and one `List<Song>` collection, `songs`.

I want to zip `titles` and `URLs` using Linq Zip() and for each iteration instantiating a new song object with the iterated title and URL as its corresponding properties and add the result to `songs`. As such:

`List<Song> songs = titles.Zip(URLs, (currentTitle, currentURL) => songs.Add(new Song { Title = currentTitle, URL = currentURL});`

I get the following error:

> Error CS0411  The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Zip(IEnumerable, IEnumerable, Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.    OldRedditMusicScraper

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do with a fix or workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Regards eheu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a List like so:

`var songs = titles.Zip<string,string,Song>(URLs, (currentTitle, currentURL) => new Song { Title = currentTitle, URL = currentURL });`

you could also omit the type information so:

`var songs = titles.Zip(URLs, (currentTitle, currentURL) => new Song { Title = currentTitle, URL = currentURL });`

If songs was an existing list you could make it work like so:
`songs.AddRange( titles.Zip(URLs, (currentTitle, currentURL) => new Song { Title = currentTitle, URL = currentURL }) );`

After looking at your edit, looks like you may want to do something like this perhaps:
`List<Song> songs = titles.Zip(URLs, (currentTitle, currentURL) => new Song { Title = currentTitle, URL = currentURL }).ToList();`

Comment: Good answer, I understand the method a lot better now. Thanks so much!